# Catching serilog exception in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that use serilog to log all events of my application.

My problem is what happened if serilog throw an exception and how can I catch the exception and log it somewhere else?

Comment: serilog does not throw any exception if something wrong happened,like elk server not respond or elk user,pass is wrong and so on ...

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Serilog is not behaving as you expect, this may be caused by an internal exception or configuration issue.

```
var file = File.CreateText(...);
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(TextWriter.Synchronized(file));
```

Or

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```